# Qt - QPushButtons in place of QTreeView Items

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtreeview

Is it possible to add QPushButtons for every item in a QTreeView?  For instance, when you click on a TreeItem (that is a button), it's children get displayed as buttons as well? I just have a standard QTreeView.

```
_layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);

treeView = new QTreeView(this);
QStandardItemModel* standardModel = new QStandardItemModel();
QStandardItem* rootMenu = standardModel->invisibleRootItem();

//populate TreeView

treeView->setModel(standardModel);
treeView->setWordWrap(true);
treeView->setHeaderHidden(true);

//treeView->expandAll();
_layout->addWidget(treeView);

this->setLayout(_layout);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not personally done this (yet), but you could try using QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget(). The widgets won't aren't connected in any way to the data model, so it is up to your code to update them if necessary. Also, you need to call it for each QModelIndex separately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. You must create your own delegate and applay it for your `QTreeView`.
To create delegate you must subclass [QStyledItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qstyleditemdelegate.html) and re-implement its `QStyledItemDelegate::paint(...)` method in that way what you want, also, don't forget about re-implementing `QStyledItemDelegate::sizeHint(...)` method if needed, of course.
Also, you may need to re-implement `QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(...)` method.

To apply created delegate to your view (`QTreeView`) you must create delegate and call `QTreeView`'s method `setItemDelegate` (or `setItemDelegateForColumn`, or `setItemDelegateForRow`).

Good luck!